# Raven JS callback after capturing a message

Tags: javascript, sentry

I've [installed raven-js using Bower](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/javascript/install/#bower) and I'm using [`captureMessage()`](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/javascript/usage/#capturing-messages) to send custom messages to Sentry.

After sending one of this messages, I need to reload the page. Problem is that, if I reload the page immediately after calling `captureMessage()`, the message request gets cancelled.

I've tried adding a third parameter as a callback but the function doesn't call it.

```js
Raven.captureMessage('Whoops', {foo: 'bar'}, callback() {
    console.log('Message sent!');
});
```

I've seen that some newer alternative packages support this but I will have to re-write a bunch of code for swapping libraries.

So far my only solution was to add a timeout before reloading and hope that the message request finished.

Answer (score 1):

Using the now deprecated raven-js library you can listen to the `ravenSuccess` event on `document`

```js
document.addEventListener("ravenSuccess", function (params) {
    try {
        const eventId = Raven.lastEventId()
        console.log('Sentry Error', eventId)
    } catch (e) {
        window.console.log(e)
    }
})
```

I didn't find a way to do something like this with the current Sentry JavaScript SDK (5.4.3) yet.